# Consuming different message types serialized as json

Tags: java, json, rabbitmq

I have a producer in PHP and a consumer in Java that will communicate via RabbitMQ. They are going to be working with three different message types. If the producer was also a Java application, I could just serialize the objects as raw, and then in the consumer do:

```
    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            Object deserializedBody = SerializationUtils.deserialize(body);
            if (deserializedBody instanceof TypeOne) {
                TypeOne typeOne = (TypeOne) deserializedBody;
                // process with corresponding code
            } else if (deserializedBody instanceof TypeTwo) {
                TypeTwo typeTwo = (TypeTwo) deserializedBody;
                // process with corresponding code
            } else if (deserializedBody instanceof TypeThree) {
                TypeThree typeThree = (TypeThre) deserializedBody;
                // process with corresponding code
            } else {
                // throw exception
            }
        }
    };
```

But since my producer is in PHP, I'll have to serialize the message as JSON strings.

How can I then distinguish between the three message types?

Answer (score 2):

Messages in AMQP have attributes, and you can define one for your own use specifying the type of message. But most of the time people choose to use "content-type" and "content-encoding".